# Calculate time gap as percentage of other time gap in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

`Posts` on my site have a `duration` field, of either a week, two weeks, or three weeks, stored as an integer (1, 2 or 3). I want to tell users what percentage of their post time has passed.

So if it was `created_at` 6 days ago, and the duration was a week, it'd be roughly 85% to expiry.

I've tried a bunch of things, and I feel like it should be simple, but I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((Time.now - created_at)/duration.weeks.to_f*100).round
```

Comment: Without rounding, that gives me 2.319.

Comment: Try `(Time.now - 6.days.ago)/2.weeks*100`. Should be 42%. What's the exact value of created_at and duration?

Comment: That was just an example. Another example: post is 4 hours old, duration 2 weeks. I thought that `(Time.now-4.hours.ago)/2.weeks*100
` would work like above, but that gives me 1.19...

Comment: 2 weeks = 336 hours. 4 hours is 1.19% of 336 hours. So 4 hours is 1.19% of 2 weeks. Everything is right. I can't get the problem?

Comment: Could this be a time zone problem somehow?  `Time.now` in my console gives `2015-04-03 09:33:04 +1030`, whereas `1.hour.ago` gives me `Thu, 02 Apr 2015 22:01:59 UTC +00:00`.

Comment: Okay, never mind, I'm stupid. You're right. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's timezone issue. 2015-04-03 09:33:04 **+1030** is UTC + **10 hours 30 minutes**. But `(Time.parse('2015-04-03 09:33:04 +1030') - Time.parse('Thu, 02 Apr 2015 22:01:59 UTC'))/1.hour` is still 1 hour. Rails takes care of timezones. So there is no problem

Comment: Done so. Thank you for putting up with my stupidity. Literally spent hours looking at these functions not getting anywhere. xD